# How can I redirect my pages using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am in the process of completely rewriting my old site in PHP and need to redirect the old pages to the new.

The old site made heavy use of perl scripts; in particular /cgi-bin/browse.cgi and /cgi-bin/search.cgi . I need these to redirect to /browse.php and /search.php respectively.

All other pages on the old site were fixed html pages in a hierarchical structure e.g. domain/place1/place2/place3.html . I need these to redirect to /index.php where the request is processed and PHP redirects implemented.

Currently I have this code in the .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

#RewriteRule ^cgi-bin/browse\.cgi(.*)$ ./browse.php?$1 [L]
#RewriteRule ^cgi-bin/search\.cgi(.*)$ ./search.php?$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^search\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^browse\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index\.php

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?%1 [L]
```

This does not currently cater for requests to domain/cgi-bin/search.cgi or similar browse.cgi, and every time I remove the # for the RewriteRules I get a 500 scripting error.

Basically, I need cgi-bin/browse.cgi requests to go to browse.php; similar for search.cgi, and everything else to go to index.php

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The first thing you always do when you get a 500, is you go check the server’s error log.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise that I had access to the error log, which I have. Seems to be an issue with the server config for cgi-bin overriding .htaccess. Now asking my host support team for help.